# Set value in service from AuthGuard before service is initiated with Angular2 and Firebase

Tags: authentication, angular, firebase

I'm trying to get the user ID from the currently logged in user to customize the data loaded from my *DataService*.
My goal is that:

1. The AuthGuard should be called before the InboxComponent is loaded
2. This *AuthGuard* should set the *user* variable in the *AuthService*
3. I should then be able to use the authService.user in the DataService

However, the `console.log(this.authService.user)` yields undefined although the `console.log(authState)` in the AuthGuard correctly logs the user information.

Any clues on what could be wrong?

**Authentication Service**

```
export class AuthService {

  public user: any;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, public auth$: FirebaseAuth) {
    console.log("Auth service state:", this.authState);
  }
```

**AuthGuard**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.auth$
      .take(1)
      .map(authState => {
        console.log(authState)
        this.authService.setUser(authState);
        return !!authState })
      .do(authenticated => {
        if (!authenticated) {
          this.router.navigate(['/error']);
        }
      });
  }

}
```

**Dataservice**

```
export class DataService {

  private userPath: string;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private authService: AuthService) {
     console.log(this.authService.user);
  }
```

**Router**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'inbox',  component: InboxComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```

**App Module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    InboxComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    EmailsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Is `AuthService` a singleton? Where do you *provide* it?

Comment: I edited my question above with the Module Import code. I import the AuthGuard in the App Module and the InboxComponent in a separate Module, the EmailsModule which I import to the App Module

Comment: Is `this.authService.setUser(authState);` working? What happens if you replace this line with `this.authService.user = authState;`?

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately that doesn't help. I tried logging out when the various services are called and adding a console.log just before I set the this.authService.user = authState;. They are called in this order: 1) Auth Service Called 2) DataService Called 3) AuthGuard's console.log(authState) - this looks like it could be the issue. Any clue why the AuthGuard is called after the DataService?

Comment: Constructors are executed when objects are created, that's why. You could make user getter inside DataService: `get user() { return this.authService.user; }`. It will still be undefined in the constructor, but everywhere else inside the service you should get correct value...

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I want to use it in all calls in the service. E.g. return at.list('items/'+userid) so I would need to make sure it's set and get the value from the observable.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how the console log in the AuthGuard can be called after the DataService is loaded. After all, the AuthGuard should protect this path and must be evaluated before the DataService should load?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130787/discussion-between-user3642173-and-sasxa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this. I had a call to my DataService in my `app.component.ts` file to get some data in my navigation. This is loaded outside the router-module and thus called before the AuthService is called. This in turn caused the DataService before the AuthGuard was called.

Comment: But how did you fix it?